# How to change the size of the y axis

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

I got this code but the solution is very tight in the Y axis, I wanna know how can I change the scale or the size of the Y axis and how can I obtain its solution cause it's not as simple as `sol/.t->n`. Thanks a lot, any help would be appreciated.

```
sol = NDSolve[{Ca'[t] == 
25 - 0.005 Ca[t] - 8 10^12 E^(-22500/(1.987 T[t] )) Ca[t], T'[t] == 
0.005 (300 - T[t]) + 
 0.01 (8 10^12 E^(-22500/(1.987 T[t] ))) Ca[t] - 
 0.001 (T[t] - 330), Ca[0] == 5000, T[0] == 330}, {Ca, T}, {t, 800}]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Ca[t], T[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 800}]
```

[image]

Comment: Append the option ``AspectRatio -> 1/2`` to your `ParametricPlot` would help; i.e., use ``ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Ca[t], T[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 800}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]``

Comment: Also, could you express your 2nd problem more clearly? I think I don't quite understand what it is that you find difficult to do.